# How to get HTML-formatted code from clipboard?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ (and several other IDEs/text editors) allow for you to copy-and-paste formatted code (as HTML, if I'm not mistaken) into applications that support it.

When you paste into applications that don't support it, you get plain text.

Is there an easy way to get the "raw" HTML, so that you can easily put it on a website?

Comment: by "plain text" you mean text without the html tags?

Comment: @EmilioMartinez that's right